# When do declared XAML list items have their dependency properties set?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, panel

**Background**

I am creating a custom wpf panel. To help lay out the child items it uses a secondary list (similar to Grid.RowDefinitions or Grid.ColumnDefinitions) that I call "layouts". Each layout has a couple dependency properties, and child items use an attached property to determine where they're placed as seen below.

```
<Panel>
    <Panel.Layouts>
        <Layout/>
        <Layout Attachment="Right"/>
        <Layout Attachment="Left" Target="0"/>
    </Panel.Layouts>

    <ChildItem Panel.Layout="0"/>
    <ChildItem Panel.Layout="1"/>
    <ChildItem Panel.Layout="2"/>
<Panel/>
```

Obviously, things are simplified a bit, but long story short: I need to process the layouts as they are added before the "Arrange" process can occur. I have created a custom collection and I can see the items as they are added (see code below), but the items just have their default properties.

```
LayoutCollection: IList
{
    public int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        // When first starting, this line always returns the default value, not the one set in XAML
        Attachment a = (value as Layout).Attachment;

        // Other code happens below...
    }
 }
```

However, when I look at the collection after the panel has been initialized the properties are all set correctly. Which brings me to my question:

**Question**

At what point during the process between XAML and initialization of the panel do the items get assigned their properties, and how are they assigned? I need to somehow hook on to that and run a bit of code.

Comment: Do you need to hook in BEFORE or AFTER the attached property's values are set/used? If it is about manipulating arrangement at all, you could have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Attached properties (`Panel.Layout` is attached property) have callback, which you can use to know when value is set/changed. You can override that callback in your Window class. Would be nice if you show code where you create those attached properties as well as specific point which cause the problem. Then it should be easy to fix it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31857866/1997232).

Comment: Why not process the layouts in MeasureOverride, before actually measuring and then arranging child elements?

Comment: @Clemens - I could push the processing into MeasureOverride, and it would make sense there. It would just be 100x simpler (give or take) if I could do it one at a time as they're added.

Comment: @Sinatr - Sorry for the confusion, I'm not talking about the attached properties on the child items, I'm talking about the dependency properties on the Layout objects. I've attached some additional code to clarify.

Comment: From where `Add` is called? Where and when you construct window? Is it MVVM? In MVVM pattern viewmodel is initialized first (layouts are initialized), then at some point view (window) is created and bind itself to already initialized viewmodel properties. Maybe you are creating window first and then initializing data, then the problem is obvious - attached property code already run and there is no mechanism to run it again (unless you use binding and update bound value as well as rise `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Show more code if you need help. Or, better, try to make mcve.

Comment: @Sinatr - this is where I'm having trouble. This is all in a wpf panel (as shown in the code above). The `<Panel.Layouts/>`is a custom property of the panel that get's populated with the `<Layout/>` items that you see in the XAML I've included. The problem is when this gets started and the list is populated, none of the values I've set in XAML are coming across. The items are added automatically when the panel is loaded, but the properties are null or default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is that the Panel layout system of WPF is not really designed to be intercepted the way you wanted it to be.

But there is a mechanism in-place to 'sync' your custom DependencyProperties. And the question is WHEN do you need these properties during the layout passes?

If it is during ArrangeOverride, you have to set `AffectsArrange`. Or `AffectsMeasure` when during MeasureOverride. There are some other flavors of this but I think either of these two can satisfy your requirement.

For example, if you choose AffectsArrange and your Panel is notified of List.Add, ArrangeOverride will be invoked and the newly added item can be used within your arrangement logic.

Comment: I've done a lot of testing and I know that everything is set by the time that OnInitialized is called. Your solution provides an elegant way to address the problem. I think I'll set AffectsArrange in the initialization of the control though.